# finding the best way to apply a property to the code

Tags: c#, winforms

sorry for confusing title.
I am using a thirdparty contorl for Spreads and it has a comboBoxCellType().
In my code there are like 20 places that I have a code like this:

```
ComboBoxCellType cbo = new ComboBoxCellType()
cbo.OtherStuff...
```

now I want all the occurences of such codes to have an extra property called listwidth =0; so
something like:

```
ComboBoxCellType cbo = new ComboBoxCellType()
cbo.listwidth=0;
cbo.OtherStuff
```

one way is just to search the code and add it manually. but I was wondering is there a better way using Inheritance and overriding to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static class that can be used to new up the ComboBoxCellType.

Something like this:

```
public static class ComboBoxCellTypeFactory
{
     public static ComboBoxCellType Create()
     {
         return new ComboBoxCellType(){listwidth = 0};
     }
}
```

With this you can new up ComboBoxCellType instances with the listwidth property set to 0 like this:

```
ComboBoxCellType cbo = ComboBoxCellTypeFactory.Create();
cbo.OtherStuff...
```

Comment: You can then search/replace instances of `ComboBoxCellType cbo = new ComboBoxCellType();` with `ComboBoxCellType cbo = ComboBoxCellTypeFactory.Create();`.

Comment: hmm..what is this compile error? "Static class 'MyApplication.ComboBoxCellTypeFactor' cannot derive from type 'FarPoint.Win.Spread.CellType.ComboBoxCellType'. Static classes must derive from object."

Comment: I'm not sure why you would be getting that error. Did you create a new file to contain the `ComboBoxCellTypeFactory` class?

Comment: yes. a new class....now I wanna just put this class inside the main class, like a nested one. or maybe I just remove the "static" modifiers? is it ok to remove them?

Comment: If you remove the `static` modifier you will have to create an instance of `ComboBoxCellTypeFactory` before you can call the `Create()` method. I recommend just creating a new file containing the  static class and static method. Then you can call it from anywhere in the application without first creating an instance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4364/discussion-between-michael-minton-and-bdota)

Comment: ok found the problem: static classes cannot use inheritance. so we should remove the inheritance part from this new class and then it works.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate the creation and initialization of a `ComboBoxCellType` to a method and call that method from every place you previously did this.

In general, if you find yourself repeating code, see if you could extract the code into a method that you can call. Keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Something like:

```
private ComboBoxCellType BuildComboBoxCellType()
{
  ComboBoxCellType cbo = new ComboBoxCellType()
  cbo.listwidth=0;
  cbo.OtherStuff...

  return cbo;
}
```

And in your original code:

```
ComboBoxCellType cbo = BuildComboBoxCellType();
```

Comment: hmm, sounds good. would you please show me some code sample I can get an idea? thanks

Comment: ohok, thanks...well cbo.OtherStuff is very different in different locations of code. it is not something I can facotr it. so the only common thing to facotr is cbo.listwidth=0; ... in that case I am still touching all places of the code to apply this new BuildComboBoxCellType() ...which is again like writing cbo.listwidth =0 everywhere that is needed.  Inheritance does not work in this situation?

Comment: @BDotA - Depending on what `OtherStuff` is, you _may_ be able to factor it out using a `Func<T>` or `Action<T>` delegate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source code I would suggest placing a this.listwidth = 0 in the constructor of your ComboBoxCellType.